# Get image coordinates by click on renderer in XTK

Tags: javascript, renderer, xtk

I am looking at the [example](http://lessons.goxtk.com/13/) in XTK.

There are one renderer3D and three renderer2D instances.

How can I determine image coordinates by mouse click event (either on 3d renderer or on one of the 2d renderers)?

I need it for further labelmap modifications like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28457556/2333458) code snippet.

**UPD**
for 2d renderers I found `xy2ijk` method which does what I need:

```
var pos = slice2d.interactor.mousePosition;
var ijkPos = sliceY.xy2ijk(pos[0], pos[1]);
```

I still need to do the same thing for 3d renderers.